# UIVIEWCONTROLLER how it works and can i use their methods?

Tags: swift, methods, uiviewcontroller, subclass, nsobject

According to my studies and understanding there are some classes such as UIViewController and NSObject and so on .first of all where can i find a list of these classes name or if there are some of them to recomend that would be awsome and how would i know what are the methods of these main classes that i use in my subclass 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use apple's documentation for the UIKit API. Have a look in here it's everything you are looking for

[Apple UIKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/)

Keep in mind that you don't need to remember all this. Many developers search documentation in order to find particular methods or subclasses that need to implant in their code